# Conflict when installing robot_upstart

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ubuntu, ros-noetic, robot-upstart

I'm facing an issue with installing the robot_upstart package.
whenever i run `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-robot-upstart`,i get an error that says

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal: /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg !=
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal: /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg !=
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Looking forward to your reply! Thank you:)

Comment: Please edit your question with enough information to reproduce how you've setup your system to support installing these packages. There's likely an issue with what you did that we can help with if you can share.